# Eloquent With A One to One 'Like' Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I currently have an Eloquent Model that I have tried to simplify for this example and has a similar structure to the below.

```
class Student extends Model {

    public function classes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Classes', 'class_code','code');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Events', 'event_code', 'code');
    }

}
```

Every student has an assigned code. Hence a student can be matched to classes or event in a one to many / one relationships via this code. The issue is the relationship of the event. The code is slightly different.

In classes, the code will be 11-ABCD.00

For events, the code is: 11-ABCD

The decimal point is missing in the event code but otherwise, the code is the same. The decimal point simply allows for finer sub-divisions. For relationships, it does not matter and may not always exist i.e. A student may not have a class or event related to them.

I can manually retrieve an Event record like this:

```
class Student extends Model {

public function events($code)
{        
        $code = explode('.', $code);

        if(count($code) > 0)
        {    
            $code = $code[0];
        }

        return Event::where('code', $code)->first();
    }
}
```

But this isn't in the true spirit of eloquent when I want to retrieve an entire collection e.g.

```
$results = Student::with('events')->first();
```

In short, can I design the relationship of the event to automatically take the key 'code' and strip it so that I can retrieve the records that are relevant?

Example Coding:

Student (Model) (10-ABCD.10)

Classes (One to Many) (10-ABCD.10)

Event (One to One) (10-ABCD)

Comment: In short, yes you can. I could help you, but in order to do so I need a little better explanation about your coding system (I mean the assigned code to `user`/`class`/`event`

Comment: I've added an example to my question. The student is the core model. They have a one to many relationships with classes, so their code (10-ABCD.10) will match to their many classes. They have a one to one to their event (10-ABCD)

Comment: As far as I can see, you are using a computed value as a foreign key (in your Event model). I mean, the `code` value in the `events` table, doesn't exist in the `users` one, am I right?

Comment: Also, if your `User` has a `hasOne` relationship with `Event`, why not just store the user's `id` as the foreign key?

Comment: The database and relationships are unfortunately not mine, so I have no input on the keys. Also, there is a requirement that the decimal point exists for the student code but that part of the code is not present in the events model.